# Prepend BOM to plone.namedfile field

Tags: utf-8, plone, blob, zope, byte-order-mark

I need to prepend the BOM to a NamedBlobFile field on my Dexterity type to make Windows users happy, but leave the file in blobstorage intact.

What is the recommended way to hook into Zope's file streaming without changing the actual file on the filesystem?

Comment: There is rarely a need to prepend a BOM to a file. Is this UTF-8?

Comment: Yep, it's UTF-8. Plain text files, that open (be default) in Notepad on Windows.

Comment: And without the UTF8 BOM that doesn't work? I understood that it is optional even for Notepad (but it'll write one when saving).

Comment: Nope, it doesn't. In Notepad, that is. I think I'm ready to give up on Notepad and just force everyone off of Notepad.

Comment: That would be the preferable solution! Having to hack NamedBlobFile serving has a lot of potential to be *painful*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go a different direction:

- Ban Notepad. Really, broken software is broken software, you can only go so far to fix it's shortcomings.
- Save UTF-8 files *with* the BOM; U+FEFF means "ZERO WIDTH NO-BREAK SPACE", 'normal' software will mostly ignore it.